# Variable (short) changes values when copied/assigned

Tags: c

I have the following code:

```
  short num_short = 1;
  int possible_new_short = 1;
  valid = 1;

  while (valid) {
    possible_new_short = num_short * 10;
    printf("----\n");
    printf("Num Short: %d\n", num_short);
    printf("Possible New Short: %d\n", possible_new_short);
    if (possible_new_short % 10 == 0) {
      num_short = possible_new_short;
      printf("New! %d\n", num_short);
    } else {
      valid = 0;
    }
    if (num_short == 0) {
      valid = 0;
    }
  }
  printf("num_short: %d\n", num_short);
```

The output is as follows:

```
----
Num Short: 1
Possible New Short: 10
New! 10
----
Num Short: 10
Possible New Short: 100
New! 100
----
Num Short: 100
Possible New Short: 1000
New! 1000
----
Num Short: 1000
Possible New Short: 10000
New! 10000
----
Num Short: 10000
Possible New Short: 100000
New! -31072
----
```

As you can see, the value of `possible_new_short` is `100000`, but when reassigned to `num_short` it goes to `-31072`. Why is this happening?

I'm completely new to C and my guess is that the `num_short` variable overflowed. Because `num_short` and `possible_new_short` are stored in different slots of memory, one can overflow and one can't?

What are some best practices to guard against this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guess is correct, `num_short` is of type `short`, which is usually 16-bit in most machines today.

A 16-bit signed integer can hold values at most  2<sup>15</sup> − 1, which is `32767`. The last value `100000` overflows.

`possible_new_short` doesn't overflow because its type is `int`. In general, think about the maximum possible values that a variable holds, and define its type accordingly. For example, you can use `long` or even `long long` instead.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you. Having `possible_new_short` as an `int` is the part I missed.

Answer (score 1):

shorts have a range of –32,768 to 32,767 on most systems.Therefore when you try to assign num_short with 100000 it overflows and causes undefined behaviour.But as possible_short is int it has a range of –2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 and can store the value of 100000.So make your num_short of appropriate type.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what is happening. I am sure you'd be getting a number of compiler warnings. Never ignore them. Your following line

```
if (possible_new_short % 10 == 0) {
   num_short = possible_new_short;
```

Here you are assigning num_short to a value which is greater than maximum short can hold when `possible_new_short` becomes 1000000, it's hex value is `0xFFFF8640`. When you assign it to a short - higher order 2 bytes (`FFFF`) are ignored and value becomes `0x86A0` whose value if you print using `%d` is -31072.

So your assignment is a problem.

Comment: Actually, I haven't gotten any warnings from the compiler. I'm using `gcc` on my mac (just the one that comes pre-installed). Is there anything I should change?

Comment: Did you compile with `-Wall `? Try compiling with it.

Comment: Indeed it doesn't give warning with -Wall - strange!! :) I'd expect it to give that warning.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't. Thanks for the tip though!

Answer (score 1):

The C offers various data types. It for us to choose from the provided types as per our requirement. The range  of short is always less than an int, The range of values which both can hold is environment dependent. In the above code snippet you are trying to assign a value **100000** to the type short. Since this value caanot be stored in the short variable it is overflowing the variable and it is giving you the value from the other end of the range. This could be understood as

The size of char is 1 byte so the range of values for **signed char** is **-127 to +127** Now if you assign **char a=127**. It works fine but try assigning **char a=128**. When you will print the value of a you would get **-127** Which is from the other side of the range.

Similarly for the **unsigned char** the range of value will be **0 to 255**. So when you will try to assign a value greater than range say **unsigned char a=256**. You will get the value from other side of the range. When you will print the value of a it will give you **zero**

This could be understood by the binary representation of the number 
We will consider the **unsigned char**
Since char is of 1 byte i.e 8 bit so when we try to assign 256 this is what the assingment looks like binary representation for 256 is **0000000100000000** The least significant bits are all 0 which are eventually assigned to **a** as it can hold only 8 bits that is why we get 0 when we assign 256 to a. The same thins is also happening in your case.

To make the above code snippet work fine declare the variable num_short as **int**

Comment: It's not specified whether `char` is signed or unsigned.

Answer (score 0):

`short` (on your machine) is a signed 16-bit (2-byte) type.

If you assign `100000`, which needs 17 bits: `1 10000110 10100000` (grouped per byte), the most-significant bit gets chopped off.

The result is that your `possible_new_short` will end up as `10000110 10100000`, which is `-31072`.

To guard against overflow you could check using `INT16_MAX` (and `INT-16_MIN`).